# Is it possible to evaluate a normalizing constant for a characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f$ and characteristic function $\varphi$. Say we know $\varphi$ up to a constant $c$. Is it possible to evaluate this constant using $\int f(x)dx=1$ (or by another method)?

(Motivation for question: I was thinking about this question because of the following type of question: Say $X$ is a random variable with (uniform) density $f(x)=c$ with support $[0,5]$. Calculate $c$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(t):=\mathbb Ee^{itX}$ then $\phi(0)=1$.

So if $\chi(t)$ denotes the characteristic function up to a constant then: $$\phi(t)=\frac{\chi(t)}{\chi(0)}$$

Comment: Great. What if $\phi(t;c):=\mathbb Ee^{ictX}$ i.e. the constant is in the exponent?... Just realized that $c$ cannot be evaluated because $cX$ would also be a random variable.

Comment: Your $\phi(t,c)$ can be recognized as $\phi_{cX}(t)$ i.e. the characteristic function of $cX$. Also note that $\phi_{cX}(t)=\phi_X(ct)$. Indeed: $c$ cannot be evaluated (as you added to your comment).

Comment: Thanks. So if I were to summarize, we can evaluate such a $c$ if and only if $\chi(0;c)$ is not a constant i.e. depends on $c$ and we would choose $c$ so that $\chi(0;c)=1$.